# В каком момент жизненного цикла Activity становится видимой на экране?

Tags: android, activity

Правильно ли я понимаю, что Activity становится видимой на экране после вызова onResume(), а не onStart()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ответ:** После onStart() видно, но нельзя взаимодействовать. После onResume() видно, и можно взаимодействовать.

Comment: Всё же заблудился в 3-х соснах, ответ после onStart();

Comment: @Вади Конюх, сори допустил ошибку. Из описания видно что на момент вызова onResume() Actvity уже видно, но оно еще не доступно для взаимодействия.

Comment: @ Sviat Volkov, уже был поправлен на момент вашего комментария.